# How do i get the color of a webpage inside of a webview android

Tags: android, webview

mi question is simple, i want to get the background color of the webpage that i enter in my webview, and then with the value change the color of a button. Is this posible?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is using javascript. Just write a javascript function that does what you want an in your android side, call your javascript method like this

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:functionName(\"" + argument + "\")");
```

*Also, to be able to run javascript in webView, you must enable it first like this `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`*

Comment: Sorry but I am new developer, what javascript function can i write to get the background color?

Comment: Check http://www.w3schools.com/js/ also http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_css_bgcolor